# Problema Para enviar Email desde SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

Intento enviar correos desde `SQL` `Server` pero me marca un error.

Configuro las opciones tiene `sql` con mis datos pero no me lo envía, intente con cuentas de `gmail` y si funcionan, si los manda, intente cambiar el puerto, la `conexión` con `SSL` y nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me marca el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero es que tiene que utilizar datos reales como: Servidor, Puerto, Correo y Clave existentes. Claro , Suponiendo que estas usando como domino ejemplo.com  Que servidor de Correo estas utilizando ?

Comment: En la imagen cambien mi dominio por ejemplo los datos que pongo son reales, de echo envío correos con una librería con ese dominio correo y puerto y funciona, el detalle es que en sql server no me envía el correo

Comment: si el puerto es 587, normalmente utiliza SSL. Veo que no tienes marcada la opción SSL.

Comment: Ya intente marcando SSL, cambie el puerto y nada, no lo envía

Comment: ¿Puede ser que el servidor de SQL Server no tenga conexión con el servidor de correo? En teoría, si el usuario y contraseña son correctos, no debería de tener problemas de autenticación si hay conexión.

Comment: Si te marca invalid HELO name es porque no esta autenticando correctamente con el servidor SMTP. Revisa los permisos como te indican en la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Yo mando los mails desde Transact-SQL.

**NOTA:** Te voy a poner todo lo que puedes hacer con una breve explicación, esto no quiere decir que necesites todos los elementos (lo que empieza con el @), no te agobies por la cantidad de código, leelo y usa lo que necesites.

1. crear una cuenta:

```
    sysmail_add_account_sp   
         @account_name =  'prueba3', /*Nombre de cuenta*/
         @description = 'Esto es una cuenta de prueba', /*Descripcion de la cuenta*/
         @email_address =  'pruebainmotech@gmail.com' ,  /*Correo de Origen*/
         @display_name =  'name2' ,  /*El nombre que sale encima del Asunto*/
         @replyto_address =  'noresponder@gmail.com' ,  /*La cuenta a la que el cliente manda las respuestas*/
         @mailserver_name =  'smtp.gmail.com', /*Dirección IP del servidor de correo SMTP*/
         @mailserver_type =  'SMTP' , /*Tipo de servidor de correo*/
         @port =  '587',  /*Numero de puerto para el servidor de correo electrónico*/
         @username =  'prueba3', /*Nombre de usuario*/
         @password =  'Admin1234', /*Contraseña de Usuario*/
         @enable_ssl =  TRUE /*Cifra el correo para que sea más seguro (BIT)*/
```

2.Crear un Perfil:

```
sysmail_add_profile_sp @profile_name = 'prueba3'
```

3.Juntar Cuenta con perfil:

```
sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp 
    /*@profile_id = '5'  /*se asocia el perfil a la cuenta mediante la id de prfil*/*/
    @profile_name = 'prueba3' ,  /*se asocia el perfil a la cuenta mediante el nombre de perfil*/
    /*@account_id = '5'  /*se asocia el perfil a la cuenta mediante la id de la cuenta*/*/
    @account_name = 'prueba3',  /*se asocia el perfil a la cuenta mediante el nombre de cuenta*/ 
    @principal_name = 'public', /*se pone en public para que pueda mandar correos               sin problemas*/
    @sequence_number = 1 /*Determina el número de cuentas que se utilizan en el perfil (INT)*/
```

4.Mandar el mensaje:

```
EXEC sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name='prueba2', /*El nombre de perfil del emisor*/
    @recipients='mtonorte@inmotechnia.com', /*dirección/es de correo a los que se envían el mensaje,
    si se manda a más de uno, se separan mediante una coma*/
    /*@blind_copy_recipients = 'mtonorte@inmotechnia.com', /*No muestra el destinatario en el correo*/*/
    @reply_to = 'mtonorte@inmotechnia.com', /*El correo al que el destinatario va a enviar la respuesta
    NOTA: Si se deja null, la respuesta se envía a @reply_to_address especificado en la creación de
    cuenta*/
    @subject='mensaje de prueba 2', /*Asunto del mail*/
    @body='Con archivo esto es un mensaje de prueba 2',
    /*Mensaje*/
    @body_format = 'HTML', /*Define el formato del mensaje, tiene 2: TEXT y HTML
    En el modo TEXT, el mensaje se envía con una fuente, tamaño y color predeterminado
    En el modo HTML Decides todo mediante marcas HTML ejemplo:
    @body='esto es un mensaje de <br><span style="color:red;">prueba body_format html con color 2</span>',*/
    /*@importance = 'Low', /*Define la importancia del mensaje, por defecto en medio, en high pone una
    exclamación roja en el mensaje y con low pone una flecha azul*/*/
    @sensitivity = 'Personal', /*Define la sensibilidad del contenido, el defecto es normal, y se
    pueden poner los valores Personal, Privado y confidencial*/
    @file_attachments = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\img\logos\favicon.jpg', /*Adjunta un archivo al mensaje
    NOTA: Hay que poner la ruta absoluta del archivo*/
    @query = 'select * from clientes', /*La sentencia que se va a mandar*/
    @execute_query_database = 'inmo_derio'  , /*La BD donde se ejecuta la sentencia*/
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1, /*Define si la sentencia se va a mandar en una pestaña a parte
    o si se va a mandar junto al texto*/
    @query_attachment_filename='warning.csv', /*Define el formato del archivo, no vale cualquier
    formato, .csv es uno de los más comunes y si funciona, pero otros como .pdf no 
    NOTA: no incluir este si noestá incluida @query*/
    @query_result_header = 0, /*Especifica si la sentencia se manda con el nmombre de columna o solo
    con el contenido*/
    @query_result_width = 1500, /*Indica el ancho que va a ocupar la sentencia*/
    @query_result_separator = ',', /*Define el carácter que separa los datos resultantes de la sentencia*/
    @append_query_error = 0, /*Especifíca si se debe de mandar el correo cuando la sentencuia devuleve
    un error*/ 
    @query_no_truncate = 0, /*No se, solo se que es excluyente con @query_result_no_padding*/
    @query_result_no_padding = 1; /*Define si hay espacio entre los datos resultantes de la sentencia*/
```

**NOTA 2:** El usuario tiene que tener permiso de ejecución sobre el proceso `sp_send_dbmail` y tener el rol de `DatabaseMailUserRole`, ahora te digo como se hace:

Para dar permiso sobre el proceso:

```
Use msdb
Go
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_send_dbmail  TO @user;
```

Para dar el Rol:

Haces doble click en el login del usuario, te vas a la pestaña de UserMapping, haces click en el recuadro de la BD msdb y le das el siguiente rol: DatabaseMailUserRole

[image: foto--1]
[image: foto--2]

**NOTA 3:** Al ser un proceso de SQL Server, lo puedes meter en un trigger y hacer que se mande un correo cada vez que se ejecute una insert en x tabla (por ejemplo)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, un saludo

Comment: El 1er paso no se pone en modo código, no sé por qué

Comment: No sé que opinar de tu respuesta. Creo que es muy informativa pero no responde la pregunta directamente. Estoy seguro de que el problema es cuestión de permisos por seguridad y no configuración desde SQL Server.

Comment: De ser ese el caso, que pruebe solo con el último paso, que es donde explico los permisos @LuisCazares

Comment: Entiendo, pero no me manda los correo aun

Comment: @javiertxu18 tendrá algo que ver que la ip de mi servidor tiene ip:2083

Comment: Prueba a darle el rol de sysadmin al usuario con el que quieres mandar el correo, si el equipo tiene internet no tendría que darte ningún problena la ip (supongo que 2083 es el puerto)

Comment: Yo sí creo que es una buena respuesta. Los wizards de MSSQL no son lo más confiable (que ya los sufrí tratando de deshacer una replicación fallida de tablas) y siempre será más confiable configurar las cosas por T-SQL.