# SQL Server no envia Email

Tags: sql-server, email

Os indico donde esta montado y que versión tiene el SQL server:

- SQL server Standard 2014
- SSOO: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter

Como disponemos de agente usamos correo para cuando termine un Job.

La manera en cual he configurado el correo fue siguiendo el siguiente Tutorial:
https://tutorialesit.com/sql-server-como-configurar-el-envio-de-notificaciones-por-correo-electronico/

Hubo un tiempo que me funciono pero un dia empezo de manera intermitente en plan algún día si otro no y ahora no me va.
El error que aparece es el siguiente:

```
Fecha       18/03/2022 13:01:13
Registro        Correo electrónico de base de datos (Registro de Correo electrónico de base de datos)

Id. de registro 117
Id. de proceso  6780
Id. de elemento de correo   33
Modificado por última vez   18/03/2022 13:01:13
Última modificación por sa

Mensaje
No se pudo enviar el mensaje de correo a los destinatarios a causa de un error del servidor de correo. (Enviando mensaje de correo electrónico utilizando la cuenta 5 (2022-03-18T13:01:13). Mensaje de excepción: No se pueden enviar los mensajes de correo al servidor de correo. (Error al enviar correo.).
)
```

Como veis el error no me desvela mucha información por lo que estuve mirando en diferentes sitio para ver si podia realizar los pasos y en algun sitio me fallaba.
Use esta entrada de stackoverflow y he seguido el comentario de abajo paso a paso.
[Problema Para enviar Email desde SQL SERVER](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/263574/problema-para-enviar-email-desde-sql-server)

Pero llego al punto de que encola el mensaje, pero no logro saber ya nada mas, lo encola y falla, y no recibimos nada al server SMTP. El que usamos es smtp.Office365.com

¿se puede ajustar mas para ver el error? ¿o disponéis de alguna solución?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Un saludo

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes. Más allá de qué tutorial usaste o no, la cosa es ver cómo está configurado tu servidor. Sin revelar contraseñas, qué parámetros usas (los de _database mail account_)?  Y pues, incluye acá lo que ves cuando seleccionas View Database Mail Log (o eso es lo que dices que te aparece como error?) Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Procura no añádir detalles en los comentarios. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).